# Looking for a device to record a stereo signal on USB drive/SD card without a laptop

Tags: usb, audio, music, audio-recording, sd-card

What I want is to record a stereo input signal on a USB drive or SD card, without the use of a laptop.

The reason is I play in a rock band, and during rehearsals it would be nice to be able to record the output of our mixing device. We don't need all 16 outputs, just a simple stereo mix will do (we have mic-ed/lined all singers/instruments).

I want a cheap solution (otherwise I can bring my laptop), but I see many dictaphones with microphones builtin, but not with a (stereo) audio input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search for "stereo recorders" turned out plenty of results, such as [Tascam DR-05](https://www.samash.com/tascam-dr-05-portable-handheld-recorder-tdr05xxxx?cm_mmc=GoogleShopping-_-Recording-_-Channeladvisor-_-Tascam%20DR-05%20Portable%20Handheld%20Recorder&utm_source=GSH&utm_medium=CSE&utm_campaign=Channeladvisor&CAWELAID=1594747829&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=61896926156&CATCI=pla-555309262683&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIoZ_usYrU3gIViJyzCh3f7A1rEAQYAiABEgJpTfD_BwE).  It has two unidirectional audio microphones, pointed to the left and to the right, which makes it work really well.  Also, it supports (and includes) an SD card.

Comment: Thanks for this answer I was hoping for cheaper (since I would expect without microphones which I need it would be a quite simple device). I don't want/need the microphones (just a line in).

Comment: Sorry, when you said "with a (stereo) audio input", I assumed you were looking for a microphone.  I guess you meant "(stereo) line input".  The other thing I should mention is, that $99 is actually pretty cheap for a quality audio recorder: I paid that much for a mono audio recorder.  But in either case, I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, I just would think that an audio recorder would be simpler / cheaper than a voice recorder, but I guess the quality of the recorded sound/DAC is higher. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since you modified your requirements, I am posting an answer, in case someone needs the first answer for the old requirements.  What you would need is, a recording mixer.  And unfortunately, those are simply not optimized for being cheap.  If you needed to replace your mixer, then it would not be a big price difference to simply buy one that does recording also.

However, you will be pleasantly surprised that I did find one professional audio recorder for less than $100.  Professional.  Sitting there in the middle of all the other products for $500, $300, $1000.  [Technical Pro UREC7](https://www.fullcompass.com/prod/252995-technical-pro-urec7-1ru-usb-sd-recorder) is a rack-mountable device that can not only record audio on an SD or a USB professionally, but has all the adjustments for treble and bass, supports RCA inputs and outputs, etc.  Very fortunate to have found one so cheap.

Comment: Thanks, a stereo recording would do, also it's not cheap. Good that you found a cheap one.